# Sort a list of objects by property in C++ using the standard list

Tags: c++, list, sorting

I am currently trying to sort a list of objects in this case students, based on their grades, student number, name, etc.

```
    listOfStudents.sort([](const Students& student1, const Students& student2)
        {
            if (student1.getStudentNumber() == student2.getStudentNumber())
                return student1 < student2;
            return student1.getStudentNumber() < student2.getStudentNumber();
        });
```

**This is the code I am currently using** to sort the list based on their student number but it points an error to the student1 and student2 saying "The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible".

**Here is the code for the Student Class:**

```
class Students {
    int studentNumber;
    string studentName;
    int grade1;
    int grade2;
    int grade3;
    int grade4;
    int grade5;
    int total;
public:
    void setStudent(int number, string name, int g1, int g2, int g3, int g4, int g5, int total) {
        this->studentNumber = number;
        this->studentName = name;
        this->grade1 = g1;
        this->grade2 = g2;
        this->grade3 = g3;
        this->grade4 = g4;
        this->grade5 = g5;
        this->total = total;
    }

    int getStudentNumber() {
        return this->studentNumber;
    }

    string getStudentName() {
        return this->studentName;
    }

    int getGrade1() {
        return this->grade1;
    }

    int getGrade2() {
        return this->grade2;
    }

    int getGrade3() {
        return this->grade3;
    }

    int getGrade4() {
        return this->grade4;
    }

    int getGrade5() {
        return this->grade5;
    }

    int getTotal() {
        return this->total;
    }
};
```

and this is the implementation part

```
    list <Students> listOfStudents;
    Students students;
```

The above codes are currently producing errors about the list type qualifiers etc.

Did I miss something? Im sure I did. Thank you in advance for relieving my idiocy.

Comment: please post a [mcve] and the complete verbatim compiler error message

Comment: Please include error messages in your question. Also, can two `Student`s have identical student number?

Comment: Your getters are not `const`. They should be if you want to be able to call them on a `const` object.

Comment: oh wait... your methods are all non-const. You cannot call them on `const` Studendts

Comment: `return student1 < student2;` how is this supposed to work? did you forget calling a getter here?

Comment: `int getStudentNumber()` as a member function tells me (and the compiler) "this routine **modifies** the object, because it is non-`const`".  In general, getters should not modify the object.

Comment: You need to either define `operator <()` (or at least default for C++20 and later) for `Students` class or do not use expression such as `student1 < student2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int getStudentNumber() {
    return this->studentNumber;
}
```

should be

```
int getStudentNumber() const {
    return this->studentNumber;
}
```

and the same for all the other getters in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've read some comments. and yes I forgot to make the <() operator. I knew I had missed something.

and also making the getters const is important, and apparently, I forget them as well.

Here is the updated code and it is now working. Thanks, everyone.

In the Student Class:

```
bool operator <(const Students& studentObj) const {
    return this->getStudentNumber() < studentObj.getStudentNumber();
}
```